# Written code for P-Persistent CSMA Matlab Code

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a formula, according to Kleinrock-Tobagi paper "Packet Switching in Radio Channels", P-Persistent CSMA in Matlab and I'm stuck with the code:

```
    function pN = PiN(n,a,G) // for pi0
     pN1 = ((((1+a)*G).^n)/factorial(n));
     pN2 = exp(-1*(1+a)*G);
     pN = pN1 .* pN2;
    end

    function Pr = Pr(n,k,a,G,p)
     q = 1-p;
     g = a*G;
     pr1 = (g*(((q*(1-q^k))/p)-k));
     pr2 = (q^((k+1)*n));
     Pr = pr2.*exp(pr1);
    end

   function T = T(n,k,a,G,p) //for t-bar
    k=0;
    tn=Pr(n,k,a,G,p);
    tbar= tn*(pN/(1-pN));

   end
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.lk.cs.ucla.edu/data/files/Kleinrock/Packet%20Switching%20in%20Radio%20Channels%20Part.pdf

Comment: link for the Kleinrock-Tobagi paper "Packet Switching in Radio Channels"